# div colour not changing in .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to change the colour of a `div` randomly on each mouse click but its not changin colour:

```
div.on('mousedown', function () {
    var newColor = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
    points += 1;
    div.animate({color: newColor}, 2000);
    $('#total-points').text(points);
});
```

Through debugging I can confirm that `newColour` has been set and `animate()` has been called on the `div`.

Also I have jQueryUI referenced to its script in the local project directory`<script src="jQueryUI.js"></script>`

I suspect that it maybe something to do with the `div's` css properties overriding but not too sure where to go from here.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcLgfc60/) that displays the problem

Comment: Avoid using JQuery animate because it doesn't let you take advantage of the hardware acceleration. Use CSS transitions instead.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use backgroundColor and not color in order to change the box background. also i loaded jquery and jquery UI scripts from CDN and not locally.

```
    div.on('mousedown', function () {
    var newColor = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
    points += 1;
    div.animate({backgroundColor: newColor}, 2000);
    $('#total-points').text(points);
});
```

I forked your JSFiddle scripts and created a new one. You can find it in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pjs0e9ox/)